# What are 'F-rated' movies?

Tags: content-rating

I know about G, PG, A, R rated movies, but came across 'F' rated movies (e.g. on [this list](http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=f-rated)), does anybody know what it means?

Comment: Simple "F-Rated" search gives enough information on the matter. Please try to use google search next time before asking simple straightforward questions. Just to save communities effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-rating) has this to say about "F-rating". It is to:

> highlight films which either had a senior figure in production who was female – a director or a screenwriter – or had very strong female leads or women's issues

Or to put it more simply:

> A rating to highlight women on screen and behind the camera.

I believe the "f" stands for "feminist".

Answer (score 4):

The F-Rating is a classification for any film which

1. has a woman directing the film
2. has a woman writing the plot
3. features significant women on screen in their own right

So basically female/feminist - rated films.